# Using Other DLLs & Dependancies

Tags: c++, dll, dependencies

I have a program that uses a DLL to encrypt files. I want to write a program that makes use of the DLL so that I too can encrypt the files with the same algorithm. However, I'm new to using DLLs so I'm running into issues.

I've done some research and got something that almost works, but I think the DLL I'm trying to use has other dependencies and I don't know how to properly load them too.

Here is my code right now:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>     // Header file containing getch() prototype
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h> 

using namespace std;

typedef string(*CRYPT)(string);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CRYPT  encrypt;
    HMODULE hMod;        // handle to loaded library module
    BOOL    bRes;        // BOOL to check if DLL was successfully unloaded 

    // returns a handle to the DLL, otherwise NULL
    hMod = LoadLibraryA("ChangedName.dll");
    if (hMod == NULL)
    {
        cout << "NULL" << endl;
        system("PAUSE");
        return 1;
    }

    // returns the address of the DLL functions, otherwise NULL
    encrypt = (CRYPT)GetProcAddress(hMod, "Encrypt");

    // function call
    string enc = (encrypt)("this is a string");

    cout << "Encrypted: " << enc << endl;
    cout << "Press a key to exit" << endl;
    _getch();

    bRes = FreeLibrary(hMod);
    return 0;
}
```

When ran, I get:

```
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\REMOVED\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Project1\Debug\Project1.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp120d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr120d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\REMOVED\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Project1\Debug\L2TowerUtils.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr110.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp110.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mscoree.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in Project1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.
Unhandled exception at 0x7791BDA1 in Project1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.
```

The error occurs on `string enc = (encrypt)("this is a string");`

Comment: what line is the crash on?

Comment: `string enc = (encrypt)("this is a string");`

Comment: My guess is that `GetProcAddress` is returning `NULL`. Have you checked that?

Comment: I believe it is returning NULL, but I don't know how to fix it. :(

Comment: Using DependancyWalker, I don't see any functions listed. All I get is a list of other system DLLs and a note in red stating `Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.`

Comment: @user1960364: That's not a fatal problem. What _is_ a fatal problem is  that `ChangedName.Dll` does not export `Encrypt`. (DependencyWalker should list all exports)